# How can i add my UINavigationController and my Tabbar to UIAddressBook

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I want to use my custom UINavigationController and UITabbar for my app it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse it is possible to make custom navigationController with UITabbar.Though i suggest you to take a navigation based application and a Tabbar in it.

You can use the sample code

```
 NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


FirstVC *firstController = [[FirstVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

UINavigationController *firstControllerNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstController];
firstControllerNav.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[controllers addObject:firstControllerNav];

[firstControllerNav release];
[firstController release];



SecondVC *secondController = [[SecondVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

UINavigationController *secondControllerNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: secondController];
secondControllerNav.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[controllers addObject:secondControllerNav];
[secondControllerNav release];
[secondController release];

self.tabbar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabbar.viewControllers = controllers;
self.tabbar.customizableViewControllers = controllers;
[self.tabbar setSelectedIndex:0];

[[self.tabbar tabBarItem] setImage:@"image.png"];
```

Cheers

Comment: So you want one of the tabs as ABPeoplePickerNavigationControl?

Comment: ya let suppose instead of secondController I want to add ABPeoplePickerNavigationController ,

Comment: That can be achieved but by using the modalViewController to present the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController,the tabbar won't be visible.

Comment: So ideally what i suggest is keep the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController as a sub item of the main tab.

Comment: i mean to say dont keep the Address book directly as a tab as if so you won't be able to view the tabbar,keep it inside the root of any one of the tabs...

Comment: Sorry but for this can't provide you code,its an idea,u will have to implement...

Answer (score 0):

[UINavigationController initWithRootViewController],
Use for navigation class.

And about UITabbar use like
tabbar addItems,
[tabbar.items objectAtIndex:X];
X means 0 1 2 3 4 ..

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution

```
ColorController * red = [[[ColorController alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor redColor] name:@"Red"] autorelease];
ColorController * green = [[[ColorController alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor greenColor] name:@"Green"] autorelease];
ColorController * blue = [[[ColorController alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor blueColor] name:@"Blue"] autorelease];

UINavigationController * redNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:red] autorelease];
UINavigationController * greenNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:green] autorelease];
UINavigationController * blueNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:blue] autorelease];
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker =[[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];


tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

NSArray * sections = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:redNav, greenNav, blueNav,picker,nil];

[tabBarController setViewControllers:sections];

[window addSubview:[tabBarController view]];
```