# Multiple views on main view

Tags: iphone, xcode, multiple-views, subviews

Hi sir  i have a Screen with tab bar and navigation bar.
also having buttons on tab bar.
i want new view when i am clicking on buttons on tab bar... 
i want that tab bar and navigation bars as common to all the sub views also.
How can its possible..
Give me the reply as soon as possible. Thank You..
Anand

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666297/how-can-i-add-my-uinavigationcontroller-and-my-tabbar-to-uiaddressbook/4666316#4666316).It is what you are looking for.

Cheers.